# Find out how many lines the Text widget has

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I have a CTkTextbox and want to track how many lines of text are inside the Textbox to update its size whenver a new line is created.

When you press enter in a Textbox, a line break is created and you can track how many "\n" are inside the Textboxes content. But when you dont press enter and just let the text wrap by itsself, tkinter doesn't seem to insert a line break, so the only ever says it has one big line of text.

Here is the code I use to track the line breaks:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

window = ctk.CTk()

window.geometry("400x400")

def get_line_number(event):
    print(text_box.get("1.0", "end-1c").count("\n"))

text_box = ctk.CTkTextbox(window, width=200, height=200)
text_box.pack()

text_box.bind("<KeyRelease>", get_line_number)

window.mainloop()
```

Is there any other way to find out the number of lines in a text widget?